# jQuery :contains and click function to set cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

My few lines of code work great while testing in the Google Chrome Console, but not inside my page, placed in the footer, when uploaded to the server.

I want to search `<li>` selectors for either `English` or `Deutsch` and when those are clicked set a cookie using the [JavaScript Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li:contains('English')").on("click", function() {
        Cookies.set('language', 'en', {
            expires: 365
        });
        location.reload();
    });

    $("li:contains('Deutsch')").on("click", function() {
        Cookies.set('language', 'de', {
            expires: 365
        });
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

**SOLVED!** I had the code outside the function `$(document).ready(function() {});`! Sorry for wasting your time, but thanks for helping me!

Comment: Your code seems fine in isolation. Check the console for errors. Why do you believe this does not work? How are you reading the cookies back out again?

Comment: Maybe your script is being loaded before the elements exist in the DOM? Try and `console.log` something in your click handlers to see if they are invoked at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan because no cookies are stored and the page does not reload. :( Have no idea as I do not receive any errors in the Google Chrome console.

Comment: `console.log` something in your click handlers to see if they are invoked at all... Holy! I am so sorry for waisting your time! Had the js lines outside my `$(document).ready(function() {});

Sorry, but case closed!

Comment: In that case I would suggest deleting the question as it was a typographical problem which won't help any future visitors